# How to detect interaction with a line expanded in vertex shader in three.js?

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, shader, intersection

I'm working on a three.js project that requires crisp, thick 2D lines.

Because of [limitations in the ANGLE layer](http://threejs.org/docs/?q=Line#Reference/Materials/LineBasicMaterial), the  WebGL renderer on Windows doesn't allow thick lines with `LineBasicMaterial`.

To get around this, I'm expanding polylines in a vertex shader using [three-line-2d](https://github.com/mattdesl/three-line-2d). This works by pairing `BufferGeometry` with a simple `ShaderMaterial`.

Visually, I'm happy with the result.

Now, I'd like to detect mouse interactions with these lines. The usual `Raycaster` techniques don't work. I suspect that this is because my lines lack  geometry that three.js understands (because I'm expanding in a shader).

**My question: What are my options for picking these lines?** Do I need to extrude outside of the shader, or are there other good options?

Comment: One solution would be to expand your line the same way the shader does. Localized, do some sort of culling to identify which segments are intersectable, and then compute the expanded surface and test against that

Comment: Thanks, @pailhead. That's definitely an option. Something like [extrude-polyline](https://github.com/mattdesl/extrude-polyline) would likely help.

Still investigating. Will report back if no one beats me to it.

Comment: wow, never saw this library, looks really cool. Id just avoid doing it on the entire polyline, cull first, do it only on one segment ( you probably need to do 3 though, yours + prev + next ), otherwise it defeats the purpose of expanding it in the shader